# cyrtsal report how to hide records based on condition of a field like date

Tags: crystal-reports

hi all i have a question about hiding records in crystal report
and i am using cyrstal report in vs 2008 ,i dont know its version as i am new in crystal reporting

lets say i have report like that

```
customer_Id   customer_name OrderAmount Order_date
    0            xyz             5       03/02/2010
    1            abc             6       04/02/2010
    3            dre            7        07/02/2009
    4            kila           3        08/02/2009
```

i wana ask is there a pssibilty to hide the record if Order_Date year in 2009 and show only the records where Order_date year in 2010
to be like that :

```
customer_Id   customer_name OrderAmount Order_date
    0            xyz             5       03/02/2010
    1            abc             6       04/02/2010
```

**note i do need the data of 2009 to make a bar chart for this year

thanks in advance

Comment: i dont wrote it like that shit
the records like that
customer_id Customer_NAme Order_Amount Order_Date*******************
0               sd          2            1/1/2010*******************
1                re         3             2/3/2009******************
i only want to display recods where order date year in 2010 only and hide those where order date year in2009 to be like that
customer_id Customer_NAme Order_Amount Order_Date*******************
0               sd          2            1/1/2010*******************

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the report itself will have a bar chart on to show 2009, but the list of records shouldn't show 2009?

Two options :

The first is a subreport.

The second is to use a suppression formula in the Details section that says "Year(Order_Date) = 2009".

Comment: thank u so much i will go for the second option and get back to u
thnk

Comment: You've specifically put that formula behind the Suppress X-Y button on the Section Expert for the Details section? If so, I think much more detail about the design of your report is needed.